# Getting the value of selected option fails in select element

Tags: typescript

I have a select defined with some values and texts. I then get value from db to match it to one of the texts - this works fine (I'm doing some text manipulation beforehand, that's the localOptionsArray):

```
$('#mySelect option:selected').text(localOptionsArray.reduce((a, b) => a.length <= b.length ? a : b));
```

So the above correctly sets the text on the select element.

Now, when I want to get the value of selected element:

```
this.myId = $("#mySelect option:selected").val();
```

Then it always returns 0.

How can I get the correct `val`?

Answer (score 0):

`$("#mySelect option:selected")` can return multiple entries. So you want to select the first one in there and then get the value.

`$("#mySelect option:selected")[0].value`